# When is memory allocated for a Dim'd variable in VBA?

Tags: vba, variables, compiler-construction

I believe I read somewhere that in VBA, if you `Dim` a variable in a function or a module, it doesn't matter whether it's at the top or anywhere else in the module or function. I read that the compiler will scan for the `Dim` statements when it enters a Function or Module and allocates the memory, and then jump back to the top and start executing code.

I also believe it is personal preference for programmers in VBA to either `Dim` at the top or `Dim` as they go, I prefer the second option. My question is whether there is any official documentation on exactly how the compiler handles the Dim statements or if it can be demonstrated that the above assertion is true.

I would love to read in detail on how the compiler handles the Dim statements as to when it allocates memory, i.e., before executing the code or as it comes across the dim statements. Can that be demonstrated?

Comment: `Dim` statements aren't executed. My personal preference is to `Dim` the variable close to where it's used. Helps in refactoring. As to documentation, that is a good question, not sure.

Comment: Unfortunately asking for documentation is off topic here, and as such this will most likely be closed.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36751682/when-are-vba-variables-instantiated) should be helpful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables looks like the updated URL for the documentation.

Comment: @ScottCraner, where is asking for Documentation allowed?

Comment: Looks like @BigBen gave you the documentation.  But other than that I do not know.  I only frequent this site and SuperUser.  Neither allow that type of question.

Comment: @ScottCraner Asking for specific official documentation is allowed here, as per [When is a resource request on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386006/7296893). This question seems valid, I've cast a reopen vote.